# Where should I place a config.txt in my python project

Tags: python

The project folder hierarchy looks like

```
ProjectName
   ->src
      ->Project.sikuli
          ->myFile.py
          ->config.txt
```

Now, I have all the settings variables being stores in my config.txt and I'm using ConfigParser to fetch the values from it. The reason why I'm using this config file here is that, when this sikuli script is moved to another machine for running I can just change the values in it (like paths, username, password) rather than editing the main python script 'myFile.py'.
But the issue I'm encountering now is that I don't want the config file to be placed some where outside the project so that in my script when I try to fetch the values from it, I don't have to mention the absolute path again in the myFile.txt like:

```
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configfilePath = r'D:\MyWorkspace\ProjectName\src\Project.sikuli\config.txt'
```

Instead I want to have the relative path here so that while migrating the project from machine to machine I don't have to do any manipulations in the main script 'myFile.py'

So what I'm trying to achieve is like:
I should be able to refer the config.txt file by giving it's relative path:

```
configfilePath = r'D:\MyWorkspace\ProjectName\src\Project.sikuli\config.txt'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, get the path of the currently executed python script:

```
myPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

and then do a join of myPath and 'config.txt'

```
configfilePath = os.path.join(myPath, 'config.txt')
```

Comment: `sys.argv[0])` is not necessarily the file name of the currently running script.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be kept in the same folder as `myFile.py`, then in that Python script you could use something like this:

```
configfilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.txt')
```

Comment: [error] NameError ( name '__file__' is not defined ) is thrown

Comment: It's always defined when a script file is run, but not in the Python interactive console.

Comment: Yes martineau, instead I used os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) to get the dir name and then I did a join with "config.txt" and it worked. thanks very much

Comment: Using `sys.argv[0])` isn't the same thing as using `__file__`. The first is the script file name passed to the Python interpreter and the latter is that name of the file currently running which might be different. For example if your main script imported a module that was in a different folder and you had the statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to put the file *inside* your `.sikuli` bundle, just as you have done in your example, and then get the path to your file like this:

```
configFilePath = os.path.join(getBundlePath(), 'config.txt')
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you can fetch variables and value from a python file by importing it...

```
import config
```

I would put it in the root repertory of the project

Comment: A `.txt` file is not a Python module.

Comment: I know... I'm talking about a .py file, which you use just to put some vars.